# Добавить прокрутку в option

Tags: html, jquery

Добрый день! Есть такая задачка: как в раскрывающемся select добавить горизонтальную полосу прокрутки? Вот какой select мне нужен? Дайте советов, как это реализовать, желательно без плагинов. Спасибо!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

"Без плагинов" имеется ввиду что написать скрипт руками, а не использовать готовый плагин.

Answer (score 1):

чтобы сделать полосу прокрутки меньше, чем thumb, в свойстве :-webkit-scrollbar-track необходимо прописать рамку белого цвета

```
background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
border-radius: 10px;
border: 4px solid #FFFFFF;
border-radius: 15px;
```

и будет вам счастье

Answer (score 0):

На список стандартного селекта повлиять нельзя, т.к. он рендерится не браузером, а операционной системой. Но можно использовать js-плагин для селекта, например, [select2](https://select2.github.io/). В нем можно, в числе прочего, стилизовать скроллбар.

Например, так:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-clip: padding-box;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.25);
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid transparent;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-results > .select2-results__options::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, все получилось. Подскажите пожалуйста, как уменьшить track? Чтобы он был в линию, как на скриншоте